# How can I order by multiple fields when using Linq.Dynamic?

Tags: .net, linq

In standard linq when I use lambdas I can do the following:

```
var x = _usersService.GetAll().OrderBy(u => u.LastName).ThenBy(u => y.FirstName).ThenBy(u => u.UserId)
```

My question is how can I do that when I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic dll? I know I can do:

```
var x = _usersService.GetAll().OrderBy("LastName")
```

but how can I define additional order by clauses???

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use comma.

```
var x = _usersService.GetAll().OrderBy("LastName,FirstName,UserId")
```

You can also add `desc` or `descending` to order by descending.

```
var x = _usersService.GetAll().OrderBy("LastName desc,FirstName desc,UserId")
```